# How was Claim 5 in "A non-linear generalisation of the Loomis–Whitney inequality and applications" thought up?

Tags: inequalities, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform, oscillatory-integral

In Bennett, Carbery and Wright's paper [A non-linear generalisation of the Loomis–Whitney inequality and applications](https://www.intlpress.com/site/pub/files/_fulltext/journals/mrl/2005/0012/0004/MRL-2005-0012-0004-a001.pdf), **Claim 5** was used to generalise the case from characteristic functions to simple functions. I figured that through direct calculations, we can obtain

$$\int_U\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^nf_j\circ\pi_j(x)dx\lesssim C\epsilon^{-\frac{1}{n-1}}N^n\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^n\|f_j\|_{L^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})},$$

where $N$ is the maximum number of "steps" in each simple function, by the case of characteristic functions and Jensen's inequality.

In order to get rid of $N^n$, the authors used **Claim 5** to raise the left hand side to arbitrary power $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and obtain

$$\left(\int_U\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^nf_j\circ\pi_j(x)dx\right)^k\lesssim C^k\epsilon^{-\frac{k}{n-1}}(kN)^n\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^n\|f_j\|_{L^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n-1})}.$$

Letting $k\rightarrow\infty$, we can kill $N$.

My question is: how did they ever come up with this move? Is there a common technique or simply genius? To be honest, I would never think of raising to power $k$.

Comment: In case you're interested, although "How did you come up with this?" is perfectly good English, "How was this come up with?" is not (although, despite the beginnings of a [garden-path sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garden-path_sentence), it is perfectly clear what you are asking).  But there's not a single obvious English substitute.  "How was this conceived of?" is reasonable, though not exact.

Comment: Is this an instance of the [tensor power trick](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/tricks-wiki-article-the-tensor-product-trick/)? it seems at least somewhat similar to me.

Comment: I see this trick often used in algebraic number theory when working with [non-archimedean norms](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Non-Archimedean/Norm_(Division_Ring)).

Answer (score 6):

An instance of this idea of killing an unwanted factor in an inequality by considering an inequality for $k$-th powers and then taking the limit as $k\to\infty$ appears in the proof of the [Kraft-McMillan inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality) in information theory. The simpler case of prefix codes does not require the powers trick, but it is used in the [proof for the more general case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kraft%E2%80%93McMillan_inequality#Proof_of_the_general_case) of uniquely decodable codes.

So yes, I would say it's a known technique and once you have seen a few examples of it, it may come more readily to mind as something to try in a new situation.

Comment: it also shows up in boosting hardness results for approximating coding-theoretic problems. Typically one shows hardness for some explicit constant factor $\gamma > 1$, then boosts this to an arbitrary constant factor with tensor products. See ["Hardness of Approximating the Minimum Distance of a Linear Code" by Dumer et al](https://madhu.seas.harvard.edu/papers/1999/dms-conf.pdf) for codes, ["Hardness of approximating the shortest vector problem in lattices" by Khot](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1366232/) for lattices, though the second paper uses a non-standard tensor product.

Answer (score 6):

As Dan Romik points out, this technique is relatively old folklore by now.  Terry Tao calls this the "tensor power trick" in [a blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2007/09/05/amplification-arbitrage-and-the-tensor-power-trick/) dedicated to the subject; the two elementary applications he cites are $L^p$ interpolation and sumset bounds in additive combinatorics.

Statistical physicists have their own name for the technique (surprise, surprise): the ["replica trick"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replica_trick).  There, most models of interest generalize to arbitrary dimensions straightforwardly, but observed quantities are typically analytic functions of modeled quantities.  One copies the model in a new set of dimensions to compute arbitrary powers of the modeled quantities and then sums a Taylor series (or performs an equivalent limiting process).

Comment: I have a hard time seeing what the relationship is between the replica trick and the technique OP is asking about. It sounds vaguely related, but to say it’s the same technique and just named differently by physicists seems pretty misleading.